# Suppose that $X_1, \ldots, X_n \overset{id}{\sim} F$. Is there a function $h$ such that $h(X_1), \ldots, h(X_n) \overset{iid}{\sim} G$?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that we have $n$ **dependent** random variables distributed as:

$$
X_1, \ldots, X_n \overset{id}{\sim} F
$$

Is there a function $h$ such that:

$$
h(X_1), \ldots, h(X_n) \overset{iid}{\sim} G
$$

for a new distribution $G$ where each of the $h(X_i)$ are now independent as well? I thought about the following:

$$
h(x) = 0\cdot x + \epsilon
$$

where $\epsilon \sim N(0,1)$. However, this relies on a random variable, which I am not sure if it would be valid.

Comment: Is $G$ given to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$h= 1$ is such a  function. There are cases where $h$ is necessarily constant: e.g., $X_1=X_2$ with standard normal distribution.